# Python / Django Web service Confusion

Tags: python, django, web-services

I am trying to explore more about web service in Python/Django and to be honest i am quite confused. There are so many things like SOAPpy, XML-RPC, JSON-RPC RESTful, web service.

Basically all i want to know is what is the standard way of implementing web service in Python/Django and has anyone implemented in live production environment

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a 'standard' way, but a lot of people (including me) have used -- and like! -- [Django Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home), which is actually also used to create the web service for BitBucket (where piston's source is hosted)

Also, if you're still learning about web services, I can highly recommend the O'Reilly book [RESTful Web Services](http://amzn.to/b3KMlj) -- although it's a book with a focus on REST (which I agree is the best design pattern for a web service) it also explains RPC and SOAP, too.

Comment: Just to refresh this a bit. django-tastypie is also well worth a look and may be better suited to some projects than django-piston

Answer (score 0):

> There are so many things like SOAPpy, XML-RPC, JSON-RPC RESTful, web service.

This should give you a clue - there are different services out there that use one or more of these mechanisms.

> Basically all i want to know is what is the standard way of implementing web service in Python/Django and has anyone implemented in live production environment

There is no single standard way of implementing a web service. This is as true for Django/Python as for other web frameworks.

Different people have used Django in different ways to create a web service to suit their needs.